# How to use Eclipse debugger in Android app?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm not really experienced in working with eclipse and it's debugger seems to be extremely lame in comparison with Visual Studio's. In this question I included a screenshot of my debug perspective after some error occurred. Visual Studio (of course not in an Android project) always gives me some useful information or at least names the error. But here in eclipse I honestly see no useful information - only the line which caused the error after calling a chain of methods. Am I missing something? Should I open another window? Which information should lead me to the error?

[image]

Comment: Do you really expect Eclipse experts to help you while you call their favorite editor lame?

Comment: @Fixpoint I'm just hoping it's at least as nice as VS, otherwise I wouldn't bother asking this question. Btw. don't take it personally ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use LogCat, Luke.
Window-Show view - Android- LogCat

**EDIT** as I see, you already have it. Just double click windows which shows you blue-green-red lines. Exceptions will be there.

Comment: Right, after I hit 'Resume' a few times it finally showed the errors. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I prefer DDMS (it includes logcat) and it gives you much more information. You can open the perspective from Eclipse.